# How to reuse templates from jar in a seam project

Tags: java, jsf, seam

I want to pack my Templates in a jar and easy reuse them between projects.

So far i have been able to pack, faclets pages and .page.xml files in the jar and reuse them.
but when it comes to pages that are included with template tag etc i can't figure out how to load them from a jar.

Anyone got any idea?

I use Seam 2.2.1.Final , Jsf 1.2 and Jboss 6

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this question will help you.

[How to create a modular JSF 2.0 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199458/how-to-create-a-modular-jsf-2-0-application)

Comment: As far as I understand the OP's question, the OP was able to use packaged Facelets pages in the JAR file. So he is already using the resource resolver. I only do not really see the problem he is having with "pages that are included with template tag etc".

Comment: I misunderstood the problem, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: if i use the tag like this,   template="/layout/template.xhtml" and have my resourceresolver to look under /layout/ i get the following error  template="/layout/template.xhtml"  if i have my resourceresolver to look at /framework/ and i have it like this template="/framework/layout/template.xhtml"> it works without any problem.

Comment: The error should be WARNING [facelets.factory] /layout/template.xhtml not found at jndi:/localhost/FrameWorkTest/layout/template.xhtml

Comment: ah sorry it should be when the template="layout/template.xhtml" like this it dosn't work.

Comment: Look in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587808/how-to-use-facelets-composition-with-files-from-another-context)