# How to see message.properties in a Jar using JSF?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, facelets, gatein

Using: JSF 1.2, Facelets 1.1.15, GateIn 3.1 GA, Richfaces 3.3.3

I have some common `.xhtml` and backing bean in a JAR that our portlets can see. I did this by overriding ResourceResolver as described in other posts:

- http://ocpsoft.com/opensource/create-common-facelets-jar/
- [How to use Facelets composition with files from another context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587808/how-to-use-facelets-composition-with-files-from-another-context)

The portlets can load the XHTML and use the backing bean.

Here is my problem: I cannot get the xhtml to substitute the messages defined in `messages_en.properties`. I have tried moving the properties file outside of the JAR and placing directly in `/lib` folder. I have also tried putting a `/` in front of the name to try to get the resolver to find it. I have also put it in the components folder.

The common jar info is: I hava a `my-portlet-common-resources.jar` which resides in `server/my-portal/lib`. The jar is structured like so:

- com/portlet/common/CustomResourceResolver.class
- com/portlet/common/FilterCreateBean.class - backing bean for the common popup
- messages_en.properties
- faces-config.xml
- META-INF/components/commonPopups.xhtml
- META-INF/faces-config.xml - declares the FilterBean
- META-INF/Manifest.mf

`faces-config.xml` contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2">

    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <message-bundle>/messages_en.properties</message-bundle>
    </application>

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>FilterCreateBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.portlet.common.FilterCreateBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

</faces-config>
```

Include the messages in `commonPopups.xhtml` (partial snip):

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

    <a4j:loadBundle basename="messages" var="msgs"/>

    <rich:panel style="border-style:none;" id="addNewChainPanel">
    <rich:modalPanel id="modalNewChainPanel" autosized="true">
        <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#{msgs['filterset.modal.new.title']}" /></f:facet>

</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. Perhaps you already have a `messages*.properties` file in the classpath root of your main webapp. This one has then precedence in classloading. You need to put it in a more specific package. Put the JAR's one in for example the `com/portlet/common` folder so that it becomes member of the `com.portlet.common` package. This way it'll be available by:

```
<a4j:loadBundle basename="com.portlet.common.messages" var="msgs"/>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `<message-bundle>` entry in `faces-config.xml` has a completely different purpose. It's supposed to override JSF default validation/conversion messages which are returned by JSF default validators/converters. It is not intended to provide localized content. There you use the `<resource-bundle>` entry or `<xxx:loadBundle>` tag for. I'd remove that entry from the `faces-config.xml`.