# ui:include can not include pages with different server context

Tags: jsf, include

In my tomcat I have defined two context.

One is my application URL, which is

`http://localhost:8080/mysite/faces/abc.xhtml`

another one is used to put all my static files which maybe used by other applications.

`http://localhost:8080/files/myfile.html`

In my application .xhtml file I want to include page from the other context, for example

`<ui:include src="/files/myfile.html">`

But I always get error

`javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException:.....Invalid path : /files/myfile.html`

It looks like ui:include is not appropriate to be used here because it only looks for context related path. What should I use then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options:

1. Use `<iframe>` instead.
2. Refactor the shared files into a separate web fragment project which should end up as JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` of both webapps. Put the Facelets resources in the `/META-INF/resources` folder of the separate web fragment project. It'll be available for `<ui:include>` the usual way: [Structure for multiple JSF projects with shared code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code).
3. When on JSF 1.x, use a custom `com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultResourceResolver`: [How to use Facelets composition with files from another context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587808/how-to-use-facelets-composition-with-files-from-another-context).
4. When on JSF 2.x, use a custom `javax.faces.view.facelets.ResourceResolver`: [how to share a jsf error page between multiple wars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379995/how-to-share-a-jsf-error-page-between-multiple-wars).
5. When on JSF 2.2+, use a custom `javax.faces.application.ResourceHandler`: [Obtaining Facelets templates/files from an external filesystem or database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292272/obtaining-facelets-templates-files-from-an-external-filesystem-or-database).

Comment: Thanks to BalusC! the iframe can do exactly what I need. The second option is not valid for me because I have other backend applications which will dynamically generate static html pages who should be able to be seen from my web application.

Comment: @BalusC what if i want to load into my JSF page an external HTML resource ? here is my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038345/jsf-tag-that-load-html-from-external-source)

Comment: Would a custom resource resolver be a solution too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587808/how-to-use-facelets-composition-with-files-from-another-context

Comment: @Kukeltje: Indeed.