# JSF tag that load HTML from external source

Tags: java, html, jsf

Is there any JSF tag that we can use it in our page to load an external HTML source and put it into the resulted page :

something like this :

```xhtml
<div id="stackOverFlowPageId">
    <custTag:includeExternalHTMLSource 
       url="http://www.stackoverflow.com" [elementToInclude="body"] />
</div>
```

When a client request the JSF page that contain this code ,the server will handle this and load the page and put it into the div `stackOverFlowPageId` and send the result to the client.

Answer (score 2):

As you can make use of standard HTML tags in facelets too, just an iframe will do the work:

```xhtml
<div id="stackOverFlowPageId">
    <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" 
        height="100%" width="100%" />
</div>
```

Remember some sites do not enable to be included in frames for security reasons.

**See also:**

- [ui:include can not include pages with different server context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965157/uiinclude-can-not-include-pages-with-different-server-context)
- [Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options#answer-7469997)

Comment: I need that the server how will load the resource , a web proxy like behavior.

Comment: Then you'll need something more complex than just a JSF tag, I think.

Comment: I would never promote w3schools lol. They no good @XtremeBiker