# jsf 2.0 - How to access resources (img, js, ..) from jar without having JSF folder Structure

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsf-2

I'm working on a JSF 2.0, Spring 3.1.1 Projekt. I've an old commons-resource-jar created for Spring 3.1.1 MVC with the following structure:

> commons.jar

- --- img

  - --- myLogo.png
- --- css

  - --- myStyle.css
- --- js

  - --- myScript.js
    ..

Unfortunately this is not the structure a JSF 2.0 ResourceHandler is handling this correctly. As defined by JSF 2.0 the folder Structure should be

> commons.jar

- --- META-INF

  - --- img
        + --- myLogo.png
  - --- css
    ...

How can I configure my JSF 2.0 ResourceHandler so it can handle my initial folder structure from the old resource-library?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to share a jsf error page between multiple wars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379995/how-to-share-a-jsf-error-page-between-multiple-wars)

Comment: I have a custom ResourceResolver, but this is not reacting on img or css files, just on xhtml files. Any Ideas?

Comment: They need to be referenced by `<h:outputStylesheet library name>`, `<h:graphicImage library name>`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

get the running application instance and get the resource handler class and modify it may be one way.

javax.faces.application.ResourceHandler

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Facelets technology (which is propably the case with JSF 2.0) you may want to use a custom resource resolver.
Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587808/how-to-use-facelets-composition-with-files-from-another-context) answer about how to load resources from outside the default structure.

Comment: I'm currently using a custom resource resolver, configured in the web.xml.
<context-param><br/><param-name>facelets.RESOURCE_RESOLVER</param-name><br/>
    <param-value>com.mycompany.facelets.resource.ClasspathResourceResolver</param-value><br/></context-param><br/> But it just resolves *.xhtml and no *.jpg, *.css, ... <br/> Any ideas why?

Comment: I think the solution will be a custom <resource-handler> in the faces-config.  Does anybody know if there is an existing custom <resource-handler> implementation which is able to handle the above described folder-structure.